# Functions or VBA script to split one column in two based on content

Tags: excel, split

what would be the easiest way to do this?

The data has thousands of rows.

The data in M column is merged by data provider. I need this data split into separate columns for import.

Criteria to split:

1. Column one, named "R":
   The capital letter values are either either a.) R or b.) RS
   There are no blanks
2. Column two, named "Guidance mark":
   Values to split are values in the "exponent" after either R/RS.
   These can be values or blanks

[image: Merged]

[image: Desired]

Tried googling a lot of possible solutions, however didn't manage to find how to split this

Comment: is the guidance mark always 4 characters/numbers? What Excel version do you have?

Comment: @Ike Yeah, I just noticed it's always either 4 chacaters (alphanumeric) or a blank. Excel version is 2212

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=LET(d,A1:A4,
R,IF(LEN(d)>2,LEFT(d,LEN(d)-4),d),
gm,IF(LEN(d)>2,RIGHT(d,4),""),
HSTACK(R,gm))
```

It handles first the `R`- column retrieving the first letters except of the last 4.

Then the retrieve the last four characters for guidance mark.

Finally puttin them into a new array (`HSTACK`)

Comment: This has worked like a charm! Thank you, you've saved me hours of work!